# Load webpage's content 10s after the main load

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

do you know how I could retrieve the content of a page 10 seconds after the loading ? There is a page that loads, then 10 seconds after it load, it receives the information, suddenly I do not receive anything when I wait for the loading event.

Here is an example of a page that takes a certain time to receive its content: https://utip.io/video-overlay/433081f034fda0e01e63ca2d8ab71cca?type=tag&tag=goal-amount

In NodeJs I tried using the 'http' module with http.get() but I cannot recover anything since the information arrives 10s after loading ....

```
function getInfo(link) {
  http.get(link), function(res) {
    res.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        //Return nothing because there is nothing on the page
    })
    res.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err)
    })
  }
}
getInfo("https://utip.io/video-overlay/433081f034fda0e01e63ca2d8ab71cca?type=tag&tag=goal-amount")
```

Comment: Please post code snippet where yo are facing issue.

Comment: I think you should be using `https` instead of `http`. And if you want to delay fetching the data, you can use `setTimeout()`.

Comment: If i use `https` i got an error
`TypeError [ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL]: Protocol "https:" not supported. Expected "http:"`
The setTimeOut() doesn't Work in this case

Comment: are you importing `https`? i.e. `const https = require("https");
and then you should use `https` instead of `http`

Edit: Here is [replit link](https://repl.it/@FlashBlaze/rando-script). Try it and let me know

Comment: Not working, I think that you don't understand the issue.
I find the solution :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I find a solution, we need to use the `puppeteer` module.
`npm i puppeteer`

```
(async () => {
     let webpage;
     let browser = await puppeteer.launch();
     let page = await browser.newPage();
     await page.goto(link);
     await timeout(15000)
     await page.content().then((res) => console.log(res))
     await browser.close();
})
function timeout(ms) {
     return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```